Getting Issue with DockerHub login via a Jenkins pipeline using groovy script
When i write a jenkins pipeline to login in to dockerhub. In first attempt i'm trying to logged in with '-p' ${variable_name} but getting issue and after checking the logs, I used '--password-stdin' to login securely in to docker but again i'm failed to access dockerhub.
Note: I already installed docker in my system.
Jenkins Docker login pipeline syntax:
environment {     
             DOCKERHUB_CREDENTIALS= credentials('dockerhub-token') 
            } 

 steps {
                  
                  withCredentials([usernamePassword(credentialsId: 'dockerhub-token', passwordVariable: 'DOCKERHUB_CREDENTIALS_PSW', usernameVariable: 'DOCKERHUB_CREDENTIALS_USR')]) {
                  sh 'docker login -u $DOCKERHUB_CREDENTIALS_USR -p ${DOCKERHUB_CREDENTIALS_PSW}'
                        echo 'Login Completed'
                 }
               }

Jenkins Console Output:
+ docker login -u username -p ****
WARNING! Using --password via the CLI is insecure. Use --password-stdin.
permission denied while trying to connect to the Docker daemon socket at unix:///var/run/docker.sock: Post "http://%2Fvar%2Frun%2Fdocker.sock/v1.24/auth": dial unix /var/run/docker.sock: connect: permission denied
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // withCredentials
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
ERROR: script returned exit code 1
Finished: FAILURE

when i am using the below jenkins pipeline syntax with '--password-stdin'.
environment {     
             DOCKERHUB_CREDENTIALS= credentials('dockerhub-token') 
            } 

 steps {
                  sh 'echo $DOCKERHUB_CREDENTIALS_PSW | sudo -S docker login -u $DOCKERHUB_CREDENTIALS_USR --password-stdin'
                        echo 'Login Completed'
               }

Getting new error : Jenkins Console Output:
+ sudo -S docker login -u username --password-stdin
[sudo] password for jenkins: Sorry, try again.
[sudo] password for jenkins: 
sudo: no password was provided
sudo: 1 incorrect password attempt
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // withCredentials
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
ERROR: script returned exit code 1
Finished: FAILURE


To run docker login as a non-root user you need to follow this setup guide.

Add your user to the docker group.

sudo usermod -aG docker $USER

